# How turn off all events before new view rendering

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have several views.
In some of them I have the similar events like

```
events: {
    'click #save': 'save'
}
```

When I create and render new view old event listening remains so old algorythm still works when I already change the view.

As I know there is a `stopListening()` function but how can I activate for all previous views. 
So when I change the view/page I want disable all previous events.
How I can do that?

Comment: It's unclear what type of events you want to disable - [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) or DOM events? BTW, `stopListening` is applicable to Backbone events only.

Answer (score 2):

ID's are global, you shouldn't have more than one per page. Append your events to a class instead.

```
events: {
'click .save-btn': 'save'
}
```

Also, make sure you're disposing your views once you finished using them:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
   'click .save-btn': 'save'
  },

  ...

  dispose: function() {
    this.unbind();
    this.remove();
  }
};

var view = MyView();
...
view.dispose();
```

Cheers.

Comment: what u mean 'finished using them' ?

i switch pages, so when i redirect user anywhere i need disable all previous views. so how i can dispose all views one time?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `el`.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#wrapper_of_save_element',

    events: {
       'click #save': 'save'
    },

    save: function() {
        ...
    }
});
```

so your event is only inside your #wrapper_of_save_element (eg. a wrapper div)

http://backbonejs.org/#View-el